# JaVers why is getPropertyChanges returning a List?

Tags: javers

The title really says it all. Curious as to how its possible to have a scenario where a property can end up with multiple change entries.

Comment: Are you asking about `Changes#getPropertyChanges(String)`? Or some other method?

Comment: Yep, the documentation didnt really go very deep, and I was hoping someone was able to produce a scenario where multiple changes can be observed when calling that method. I haven't had much success.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc for [Changes](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-core/src/main/java/org/javers/core/Changes.java), it is a:

> Convenient wrapper for the list of Changes returned by {@link Javers#findChanges(JqlQuery)}.

So any property that could change more than once over the lifespan of an Entity could result in multiple entries in the getPropertyChanges list.

For example: You have an inventory tracking system that updates the number of each item in stock (using a property called "numberAvailable") each time someone buys something. One day, five different people purchase the "Blue Pen" item. At the end of that day, you call Javers#findChanges using a query that gives you all changes for the "Blue Pen" item from the past 24 hours. That gives you a Changes object that contains five changes (one for each purchase event). Each of those changes is to the "numberAvailable" property, so if you call `getPropertyChanges("numberAvailable")` then you end up with a list that contains all of those five changes.